What is a religious object used in pilgrimage called?
Character in the story has an object that he is supposed to take to a holy place. The object is central to his pilgrimage. Is there a term in English for such an object. Just to clarify, it is not a quest. He has not been tasked with this. He is doing it simply out of faith. There is an umbrella term for this in Hindi for this.(though I can't remember it right now, I will add it here when I do)
Does English have one?

@user182601 No, I am asking if there is something specific to pilgrimage. It is not a problem for me if there is not. I can just make one up for the story. Just wanted to confirm that there is no close English term I can use.(I prefer to use those as too many made-up words can ruin immersion in the story.)

The previous question linked doesn't mention artifact / artefact but the term is not specific to something carried on a pilgrimage.

@ Weather Vane Artefacts are not specifically religious. Also, the term is already used for something else in the story.

You mean something you take and bring back, or something you leave as an offering? Something identifying you as a pilgrim? Something valuable or unique of religious importance, a token, or something containing a prayer or message? What religious tradition is this? Words in English typically relate to Christian pilgrimage, while for Muslim pilgrimage an Arabic word would probably be used even in English. Pilgrim badges are traditional in Christian pilgrimage, offerings may be made, and it's also common to leave messages/prayers.

@Stuart F Something you take with you to the holy site. Taking it with you is compulsory(usually with certain restrictions on how to handle it). What is done with it after taking it there varies. Some are discarded there after performing a rite. Others are exchanged for something else. Or they can be brought back after performing a ritual on them to keep them at home or something like that.

Generally, you get them at the place of pilgramage, you don't "take them there".

Something you take and leave there could be a votive offering.

Icons and relics are usually distinguished. // Looking up 'sacristy' (the room in a traditional church building, sometimes very secure, where 'sacred objects' are stored) yields only sacred objects /  religious objects. I put scare-quotes round 'sacred objects' because many churches don't regard material things as sacred. And would see food / clothing given to the needy and a non-leaking roof as being most worthy of one's attention.

Something you would take with you is an amulet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amulet

There are mementos that people leave on a pilgrimage such as the stones at Cruz Ferro in Spain on the Camino left to symbolize lifted emotional weight or loved ones who have died.

It's a votive. Oxford English Dictionary, "votive, n. and adj.," def. 2:


An object placed in a sacred location in honour of a god, goddess, or saint, typically as an expression of thanks in fulfilment of a vow; a votive offering. Also occasionally in extended use of a piece of writing, music, or other work: dedicated to or created in honour of an individual as a sign of appreciation or admiration.


Basically, a votive is an item someone brings to a religious space to leave there. This includes objects brought to a pilgrimage site. Caroline Winter, in a literature review of votive practices in an article on pilgrimage to war memorials, summarizes their use ("Pilgrims and Votives at War Memorials: A Vow to Remember." Annals of Tourism Research 76 (May 2019), pp. 117-128):

The practice of votive deposition occurs across the globe in many cultures, where pilgrims “offer material things to their saints or gods in return for favors granted” (Notermans & Jansen, 2011, 171). It is an ancient practice that has been undertaken within institutions such as ruling dynasties, the family and especially religion, where it is for example, one of the oldest Egyptian religious customs (Pinch & Waraksa, 2009). In contemporary times, the practice can be observed at the sites of mass civilian death and trauma (Doss, 2008). Otto (2010, p. 267) found that “citified spontaneously-created shrines”, were created in response to the victims of the 9/11 attack on the World Trade Centre in New York in 2001, including tourists who came to place flags, flowers and teddy bears at the site (Greenspan, 2005). In 1997, tons of floral tributes were deposited at the palaces around London for Princess Diana who had been killed in a car accident, creating, what Gough (2008, p. 14) describes as “elaborate temporary gardens”.
As Notermans and Jansen (2011, p. 171) observe, a votive is a “material gift that has to be placed in the saint's vicinity.” There is therefore an inherent association between a votive and a particular place, which is regarded as ‘special’ due to the presence or representation of the divinity, the hero or ancestor (Bell, 2009; Blick, 2011). In their study of the Australian War Memorial, Waterton and Dittmer (2014, p. 21) refer to “the Unknown Soldier, whose body becomes invested with the sacred such that it is a holy relic.” These places are not substitutable, and lengthy journeys to them, as a pilgrimage, are almost always a necessary component in the process of depositing a votive.

Votive can be paired with a word to describe the kind of object being offered: votive art, votive candle, or generally votive offering. But votive by itself works fine. It also describes pilgrimage offerings outside the Christian tradition:

These examples show that the Ka'ba and the surrounding Meccan sanctuary were understood to be like other temples in the ancient Near East. The donation of votive offerings to temples and shrines is attested in the Arabian Peninsula and surrounding regions. (Babak Rahimi, and Peyman Eshaghi. Muslim Pilgrimage in the Modern World. The University of North Carolina Press, 2019. p. 52)


One major reason that fans are increasingly interested in pilgrimage is the
associated ema (votive tablet). (Andrews, Dale K. “Genesis at the Shrine: The Votive Art of an Anime Pilgrimage.” Mechademia: Second Arc, vol. 9, 2014, pp. 217–33. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.5749/mech.9.2014.0217.)


The first floor is dedicated to vows and objects left at the Vietnam Veterans Memorial, one of the modern-day secular pilgrimage destinations that might be seen more as tokens of remembrance or gratitude to honor the memories of the beloved rather than as a practice of faith. This demonstrates that “almost anything can become a votive once charged with meaning through a ritual act,” from a bottle of bourbon to a pack of cigarettes or a stuffed toy [...] Perhaps one of the most spectacular and unusual votives in the exhibit can be found in the first room: a custom-built Harley Davidson Police Special motorcycle offered on Memorial Day 1995 by a group of Wisconsin motorcyclist [sic] "in memory of their state's thirty-seven soldiers who remained missing" in action. (Badajoz, Joaquin. "Exhibit Explores Votives: A Human Way to Grasp at the Transcendent." The Tablet, 27 October 2018).


Thanks, pairing votive with other words works well in the story.

Relic
An object esteemed and venerated because of association with a saint or martyr
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relic
An object, tradition, or system from the past that continues to exist
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relic

I would expect a relic to be at the pilgrimage site, not to be taken there.

According to the 1955 Roman Catholic Marian Missal, Helena went to Jerusalem to search for the True Cross and found it 14 September 320. In the 8th century, the Feast of the Finding was transferred to 3 May and 14 September became the celebration of the "Exaltation of the Cross", the commemoration of a victory over the Persians by the Byzantine emperor Heraclius, as a result of which the relic was recovered and returned to Jerusalem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Cross

@DelphicOracle Relics are usually important to masses. What I am talking about could just be a trinket to rest, but have immense spiritual value for the pilgrim.

@DelphicOracle- But that is far from typical.

@EMS Then you are talking about a souvenir.

@Kate Bunting In 827, Venetian merchants stole the body of St. Mark the Evangelist from Alexandria in Egypt, where he had served as a bishop before being martyred around 68 AD. Following the relic's transfer to the Rialto, they were solemnly received by the bishop and doge of Venice and subsequently deposited in the ducal chapel. https://projects.mcah.columbia.edu/treasuresofheaven/shrines/Venice/index.php Relics are objects from a more spiritually conscious age.

@DelphicOracle - Just because you can quote some cases of holy relics being returned to a significant location, it doesn't alter the fact that individual pilgrims did not normally take a relic with them to the pilgrimage site.
